# AWN Themes and applets

Tags: themes, software-installation, software-sources, awn, panel-applets

I would like to install more applets and themes to AWN, since it's so hard to configure/personalize. Does anybody know where I could find this resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some from the software center.

- Just open up your software center and search for `awn`
- At the bottom bottom there will be a `show x technical items`. Click it.
- It will load more applets for you to install.

See attached screenshot:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

You can also run `sudo apt-get install awn-applets-all` directly from the terminal.